# Terminal copy and paste commands: Break of consistency

Tags: 15.04

Why did the terminal break with consistency of all other applications by using `Ctrl + Shift + C` to copy? Apart from the weirdness it's also much slower.

Answer (score 1):

This shortcut existed in terminals as an interrupt shortcut far before the era of graphical interfaces and copy/paste.

However, I understand your frustration. When switching from GUI universes like Windows and years of copy/pasting with Ctrl+c it's difficult to change your habits.

Depending on the terminal software you use, you can change this comportement and swap the usage of Ctrl+c and Ctrl+Shift+ c.

Alternative solution you can use like I did the [Autokey](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autokey/) software to achieve this.

> AutoKey is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows you to manage collection of scripts and phrases, and assign abbreviations and hotkeys to these. This allows you to execute a script or insert text on demand in whatever program you are using.

[image: Autokey capture]

1. When you create a new entry in Autokey, choose `Script`
2. In the textarea, paste : `keyboard.send_keys("<shift>+<ctrl>+c")`
3. In the Hotkey input field, select Ctrl+c
4. In the Window filter, select your terminal emulator by clicking on Set, then Detect window properties, then clicking on your terminal app, and finally by choosing "Window class". It will restrict this hotkey to these categories of windows.

You can do also the same, for Ctrl+v and Ctrl+Shift+c

I was a heavy user of [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows. Autokey is far less powerful and is badly unmaintained since years. However, on my distribution (Xubuntu), it still works partially, and I use it mainly for text expanding and to override shortcut definitions in applications.

Comment: It's strange to use it on my keyboard layout and unintuitive as every software I copy something from into the terminal will use the ordinary command. I use the ordinary ubuntu terminal. Is the interrupt shortcut still in use anywhere, or why hasn't this been updated to current user demands?

Comment: I think that there will be far more people complaining if the défaut behavior of CTRL+c in terminal was changed :)

Comment: It would be same as asking the US to switch into metric system. Everybody else uses metric , but it's the US legacy and technology is build around Imperial system

Comment: So would you please give me an example of its practical nowadays usage? I didn't ever use ctrl-c, except for misstypting it. And yes, the metric system mayhem seems to illustrate it quite good, but back in the real world it is certainly not something that raises the reputation of Americans.

Comment: Just updated my post to give you an example

Comment: Thanks. But I guess I stick with it, if there is no other (less complicated to use) solution than Autokey for the ordinary Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in terminal traditionally means "send interrupt signal to the running program". The terminal is being consistent with itself and its legacy, not with other programs.

More info [here](https://superuser.com/a/421468/418028)

Comment: Is there another terminal application, which integrates better with nowadays requirements?

Comment: @empedokles No. Ctrl+C is pretty standard accross terminal applications.

Comment: At the beginning, there was the command line. ;)

Comment: Interesting, creationism must be more related to computer science than I first thought. :)